# PowerShell: Where-Object condition with multi-valued attribute

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below to target only relevant users with all the specified conditions.

```
$TargetUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TargetOU -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.adminDescription -eq "Azure_Sync" -and $_.proxyAddresses -notlike "sip*" -and $_.sn -ne $null -and $_."msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress" -ne $null} | Select userPrincipalName, msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress | Sort userPrincipalName
```

I was pretty sure this was returning all relevant information, however, it seems that this returns users that do have a sip value in the proxyAddresses attribute.

I'm guessing that this is because this is a multi-value attribute? Any ideas what syntax I need to use to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$_.ProxyAddresses -contains 'sip:User.One@company.com'
```

if you have the full address, otherwise the "easy" (but slightly slow) solution I often use is

```
($_.ProxyAddresses -join ' ') -match 'sip:'
```

which just joins it together as a string and then checks if `sip:` exists in it.

Comment: `"$($_.proxyaddresses)" -match 'sip:'` would do the same thing. arrays become space delimited strings when flattened in PowerShell ...for the most part.

Comment: @Matt I often prefer using `-Join` when dealing with the custom objects powershell splits back, sometimes you end up with `msProxyAddress[]` wheras `-join` seems to call `.ToString()` on each item individually (or something)

Comment: indeed. that is why i trailed ...for the most part.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I've tested and both answers work fine. I opted to use the below answer however as regex is something I'd like to expand on so using it as much as I can in my scripts. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

### Use `-match`

If functions against collections as well. It will return all matches which we can evaluate as a boolean to satisfy the condition. Be warned that is supports regex so special characters will need to be escaped. `^` is an anchor for start of a string. So `"^sip"` would match any strings that start with "sip".

```
... | Where-Object {$_.adminDescription -eq "Azure_Sync" -and !($_.proxyAddresses -match "^sip")
```

So the part in brackets will evaluate to true if it finds a sip address. You want the opposite so we flip the result with a !

### Nested `Where-Object`

What you could do is have a nested where clause that would work on the collection of `proxyaddresses`. This would seem like more effort in your use case but as a general response to this answer it will suffice.

```
... | Where-Object{$_.adminDescription -eq "Azure_Sync" -and !($_.proxyaddresses |Where-Object{$_ -like "sip*"}) -and ...
```

So if the inner clause found any matches with sip addresses then the condition would evaluate to false because of the ! used.